# Use customElements library made with @angular/elements within an angular application prod issue because of optimization

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I am facing a weird issue and wonder if some of you faced the same issue as well.
We are actually working on a custom elements library made with @angular7 and @angular/elements using this tutorial: https://medium.com/@aks1357/getting-started-with-angular-elements-d13a967b03df

The thing is, it is working really great when running `ng serve` but as soon as we build the app using our library with `ng build --prod` we start getting errors either about a regex or a maximum stack call size exceeded.

I found the issue is about the optimization flag set to true in production mode.
But I don't see why minifying the code, breaks the thing.

Does any of you ran into this issue before?

Unfortunately I cannot share the code because, hello NDA.

Answer (score 1):

I face this issue two times it could help you.

**1st scenario** 
There is a recursive function with the wrong base case

**Second scenario** is accidentally import same file two times

Answer (score -1):

Not a solution but a workaround.

Compile your project with --aot=false and --buildOptimizer=false.

Comment: This doesn't help the situation as the bundle sizes will be huge